# Disk Utility info shows encrypted disk is not encrypted!

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, filevault, encryption

Using macOS Sierra: Disk Utility > File > New Image > Blank Image..., I created an encrypted .dmg file.

However when I open this .dmg (by entering password) and click "Info" in disk utility, it says:

> Is encrypted:    No

As I want to store some sensitive info (Credit Card info etc) in this disk and then upload it to cloud storage, I am worried if there is a bug in Sierra causing .dmg files to not be encrypted at all!

Is this normal? How can we verify if the disk is actually encrypted?

---

P.S. My filevault is On, and for my own Macintosh HD disk utility info says `Is encrypted: Yes`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper command to check if a dmg is encrypted or not is:

```
hdiutil isencrypted /../../encrypted.dmg
```

or more detailed with the encryption type:

```
hdiutil imageinfo /../../encrypted.dmg
```

Examples:

```
hdiutil isencrypted /Users/user/Desktop/Untitled.dmg
encrypted: YES
blocksize: 512
uuid: 24895029-49B1-469D-A154-B8344B7CD6EB
private-key-count: 0
passphrase-count: 1
max-key-count: 1
version: 2
```

and/or

```
hdiutil imageinfo /Users/user/Desktop/Untitled.dmg
<Enter disk's password>
Backing Store Information:
    URL: file:///Users/user/Desktop/Untitled.dmg
    Name: Untitled.dmg
    Class Name: CEncryptedEncoding
    Encryption: AES-256
    Backing Store Information:
        URL: file:///Users/user/Desktop/Untitled.dmg
        Name: Untitled.dmg
        Class Name: CBSDBackingStore
Class Name: CRawDiskImage
Checksum Type: none
Size Information:
    Total Bytes: 100020736
    Compressed Ratio: 1
    Sector Count: 195353
    Total Non-Empty Bytes: 100020736
    Compressed Bytes: 100020736
    Total Empty Bytes: 0
Format: UDRW
Format Description: raw read/write
Checksum Value: 
Properties:
    Encrypted: true
    Kernel Compatible: false
    Checksummed: false
    Software License Agreement: false
    Partitioned: false
    Compressed: no
Segments:
    0: /Users/user/Desktop/Untitled.dmg
partitions:
    partition-scheme: GUID
    block-size: 512
    partitions:
        0:
            partition-name: Protective Master Boot Record
            partition-start: 0
            partition-synthesized: true
            partition-length: 1
            partition-hint: MBR
        1:
            partition-name: GPT Header
            partition-start: 1
            partition-synthesized: true
            partition-length: 1
            partition-hint: Primary GPT Header
        2:
            partition-name: GPT Partition Data
            partition-start: 2
            partition-synthesized: true
            partition-length: 32
            partition-hint: Primary GPT Table
        3:
            partition-name: 
            partition-start: 34
            partition-synthesized: true
            partition-length: 6
            partition-hint: Apple_Free
        4:
            partition-UUID: 17698BE2-A406-43AA-9195-8D1F1AAECE6B
            partition-name: disk image
            partition-hint-UUID: 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
            partition-start: 40
            partition-number: 1
            partition-length: 195280
            partition-hint: Apple_HFS
            partition-filesystems:
                HFS+: 
        5:
            partition-name: GPT Partition Data
            partition-start: 195320
            partition-synthesized: true
            partition-length: 32
            partition-hint: Backup GPT Table
        6:
            partition-name: GPT Header
            partition-start: 195352
            partition-synthesized: true
            partition-length: 1
            partition-hint: Backup GPT Header
    burnable: false
Resize limits (per hdiutil resize -limits):
 min     cur     max 
36072   195280  60572704
```

I can only guess why diskutil doesn't show that the image is encrypted. It's either a glitch or diskutil only rates FileVault as disk encryption.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly, tried to up-vote as well, but apparently I don't have 15 points to do so.